# Wordpress ajax call to directory outside WP installation directory

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'd like to make an AJAX call in Wordpress using the designated method, with an action calling for the demo function in functions.php:

```
function demo() {

//
//
code to generate html
//
//

wp_die();

}

//

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_demo', 'demo');
add_action('wp_ajax_demo', 'demo');
```

Inside the demo function I'd like to run an URL in the same domain which will return the html to be echoed to the ajax callback.
How'd I do this? Thanks for your support. Durian.

Comment: "run a url" - what do you mean by that?  Have you checked out `file_get_contents()` for example?

Comment: @cale_b Yes, I considered using file_get_contents, but since in this way a new session is generated on each call, this option is not suitable for what I'm trying to achieve.